# Is it possible to monitor and set a max sessions / user on a Zyxel SBG3500 Wi-Fi router?

Tags: networking, router, wifi, zyxel

We use the Zyxel SBG3500 Wi-Fi router in an office which acts as our only AP. I know there is a bottleneck because of the number of users connected (20-30 / day with 1-2 devices, the max clients on the router is 32)...

But I would like to check whether some of the users choke the network/router with too many sessions. I hoped this would be possible either directly in the router interface or with a 3rd party tool, but I can't seem to find anything on this topic with this router.

(I still plan to add 2 separate APs so that the router has less work to do...).

Answer (score 0):

The max clients on AP seems more like a licensing issue than a technical limit. For 30 users with BYOD devices 32 client connections is highly undersized and a real solution here is to either increase the amount of APs or build a wireless infrastructure that is detached from the router.

If you need to limit allowed devices with your current Zyxel SBG3500 setup, the closest feature might be (*Wireless* >) *MAC Authentication*, but that requires manual administration.

Comment: Thanks Esa, what I need is actually increase the number of clients / devices that are able to connect while I keeping the network "fluid" so that most of the active users have a good experience. That's why I would like to see which device uses the most sessions / has an unusually high number of sessions open at once. It seems I will deffinitely go with the route of adding two separate APs and will let the router do only the routing to them